# Disjoint paths in temporal graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, approximation-algorithms

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and a pair of source-destination nodes $s$ and $t$. Time is divided in periods with the total number of periods denoted by $T$. Each edge $e$ is either operational or broken at each period $\tau$. A path is *good* at period $\tau$ if all its edges are operational at period $\tau$. Suppose we cannot find a path that is good for the entire $T$ periods. We seek a pair of node-disjoint paths such that at least one of them is good at each period $\tau$. What is the hardness of this problem? Is it related to some known problem? Any suggestion in developing algorithm to find the good path pair?

Comment: Is the given G guaranteed to contain a good path pair?

Comment: @RayButterworth Not necessarily. In fact we can formulate the entire problem as (1) decide the existence of such path pair (2) find them.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572528612000035 looks like a bad news (NP-complete even for $T=2$, see Lemma 2). The killer seems to be the requirement that the paths have to be vertex disjoint. Do you really need it?

Comment: @fedja Thank you very much for the reference (the result is not surprising to me). Is there any nice algorithm if the disjointness constraint is relaxed?

Comment: Only if $T$ is small, but then it is trivial. If $T$ is allowed to be comparable to $|V|$, you can enforce the vertex disjointness by introducing $|V|$ extra periods in each of which one intermediate vertex is blocked but all other edges remain open. What are the actual numbers $|V|,|E|,T$ you are thinking of?

Comment: @fedja I don't impose particular constraint on the relationship among $V$, $E$, and $T$. But the algorithm needs to work under sufficient large values of them. It is meaningful to consider the case $T\sim V$.

Comment: @Ichen, let us see if I understand you (if I do, I may have an answer for you): say you have two nodes N1 and N2. Now you would like to find a path from N1 to N2 that is broken for all t in T. But because that may well be impossible, you would like to search for two ROUTES P1 and P2  (ie two paths) such that for each t, either one is not broken. Right? Would you be happy to find a path that at each  t, wherever you are between N1 and N2, enables you to continue your journey as long as you get to N2?

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci. Thank you for your comment. Yes, you reformulation is correct, but I fail to catch what you mean by "at each t, I can continue my journey". Do you mean that I will wait some time? This is an interesting direction that I havn't thought of, but definitely pertinent to my problem and what I want to achieve. Any thought is welcome.

Comment: Not exactly. What I think you have in mind is something like this: let us say that you have a road map, and you want to go from A to B. There are many paths which you can drive through, but problem is, at each t there may be an edge broken. Now, what I was suggesting is: suppose you go from A to A1 in the first instant. You had a plan, and wanted to go from A1 to A2, but alas, the road from A to A2 is broken. Well, suppose you have an option to go to A3 instead, because at that time is ok. Now you keep choosing unbroken edges, as long as you reach B you are ok, right?

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci With that last interpretation it would be a trivial dynamic programming problem. However, If, indeed, Ichen has in mind something different from what was formally posted, it might help a lot to figure out what it really is. NP-hard problems are no fun to search a decent algorithm for. :-)

Comment: @fedja, agree 100% with you. I think Ichen's question is quite interesting, but he needs a bit more details, as far as what he is actually looking for

Comment: Thank you both. Let me clarify my problem. I want to go from $s$ to $t$. I seek a path such that no matter when I leave $s$, I can reach $t$ (suppose that the time to traverse the path is negligible). Such path may not exist. So I seek two paths such that no matter when I leave $s$, I can reach $t$ via one of them.

Comment: Yep, that agrees with the formal problem you posted and that is at least as difficult as 3-SAT (with *linear* reduction, which is a really bad sign). So, you'll have to think of whether you can settle with something weaker. I'll try to think if there is a quick reduction of your problem to some other well-studied NP-complete problem (perhaps, the same SAT. Then, at least, you'll be able to try some existing state of art algorithms on it instead of inventing everything from scratch :-)

Comment: @fedja Totally agree. I also thought of 3-SAT. The problem we are facing is how we can do in this case, given the global objective to have resilient $st$-paths. Any related thought or formulation is welcome.